# Calculating how many user inputs and average of those inputs

Tags: python, average

Trying to complete python homework task, part of the program needs to calculate how many BMIs its calculated and the average value of these BMIs after the user has written 'n'. Help would be appreciated, this is what I have now.

```
y = True

while y:   

weight = float(input("Enter weight in kg:"))
height = float(input("Enter height in m:"))
bmi = weight/(height**2)

if bmi <18:
    print("Your BMI is", bmi, "\nIt indicates you are underweight")
elif bmi >=18 and bmi <=25:
    print("Your BMI is", bmi, "\nIt indicates you are within normal bounds")
elif bmi >25:
    print("Your BMI is", bmi, "\nIt indicates you are overweight")

again = str(input("Another BMI? y/n:"))
if again == "n":
    y = False
```

Comment: I guess you should fix indentation

Comment: You could use two more variables to store the number of BMIs you've calculated and their sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an empty list `bmi_records` before going to `while` loop. Then just append new BMIs to the `bmi_records` list.

```
bmi_records = []
while ....
    bmi = ...
    bmi_records.append(bmi)
    ....

print(f'Average of {len(bmi_records)} BMIs entered: {sum(bmi_records)/len(bmi_records):.1f}')
```